# Como limitar um relacionamento 1 para muitos JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring, entidade-relacionamento

Estou usando *JPA* com *Spring Framework* em um projeto, eu gostaria de limitar um relacionamento `1:n`, quero fazer `1:5`, como faço isso?

O relacionamento é esse:

```
@ManyToOne
private Task task;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não tem como fazer isso dessa maneira. Mas como você utiliza java, você pode usar o orientação a objetos para encapsular essa lógica dentro da sua entidade. Por exemplo:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @ManyToOne
    private Produto produto;
}

@Entity
public class Produto {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Item> itens = new LinkedList<>();

    public List<Item> getItens() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(itens);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        if (itens.size() == 5) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Não é possível adicionar mais itens!");
        }
        itens.add(item);
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item) {
        itens.remove(item);
    }
}
```

Nesse caso você só teria o repository para a sua entidade de produto. A persistência da entidade Item fica toda a cargo do JPA, você só precisa adicionar os itens no produto e salvar o mesmo. Por exemplo:

```
...
produto.addItem(item);
produtoRepository.save(produto);
...
```

E da mesma forma para remover os itens.

```
...
produto.removeItem(item);
produtoRepository.save(produto);
...
```

Claro que dessa forma você tem que tratar a exception para mostrar uma mensagem mais amigável ao seu usuário.